# Applying git format-patches on local repo

Tags: java, git

After hours of searching and trying I pin my hopes on you.

I'm working at a remote pc on a project without network access. As we have a git repo server in our laboratory I'd like to add my work to the project with git format-patches. Unfortunately I can't even apply my own patches. 
When I create a patch of my latest commit, check out the previous version (before that commit) and try to apply it with "git am *.patch" I get a , ".classpath: does not match index" and a "custom.grade already exists in working directory"-error.

Content of the commit:
I added a new class to one of my projects and added some dependencies to that project using our gradle-script. I need to ask my boss whether I may upload the patch-file as the project itself is restricted.

I'd really appreciate any suggestions.

EDIT: I have now figured out that there are severe issues with whitespaces and carriage returns. Although I ignore them by bash command most patches still do not work. Another issue was created by eclipse auto-build during patch application but I still have no solution.

Regards Larimow

Comment: What is the results of `git status` before you apply the patch?  Have you changed the files that it's complaining about?

Comment: The only unstated change was the existence of my patch in the report folder. There were no new changes.I researched further and found out that there is a huge whitespace and line break issue between git on windows (my developer pc) and Linux (report server). There are merge conflicts where none should be possible.I fear that I can't use git format-patch at all.